# How do I import a class in groovy when package and folder deviate?

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, import, jenkins-groovy

I am writing groovy scripts for jenkins which defines my path names to some extent. I did try to reasearch the problem on stackoverflow and google and I could not figure out a good solution.

Here is a minimal example:
File Structure:

```
runTests.bat
vars/SemVer.groovy
tests/SemVerTests.groovy
```

The batch file executes my unit tests:

```
docker run --rm -v %cd%:/home/groovy/scripts -w /home/groovy/scripts groovy groovy tests/SemVerTests.groovy
```

SemVer.groovy

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
package vars
class SemVer {
    private String _original
    SemVer(String original) { this._original = original }
    String toString() { return "${this._original}" }
}
```

SemVerTests.groovy

```
import groovy.util.GroovyTestSuite 
import junit.framework.Test 
import junit.textui.TestRunner 
import vars.SemVer

class GetLatestSemVerShouldConstruct extends GroovyTestCase {
    void testDisplay() {
        def actual = new SemVer("Hello World!").toString()
        assertToString(actual, "Hello World!")
    } }

class AllTests {
    static Test suite() {
        def allTests = new GroovyTestSuite() 
        allTests.addTestSuite(GetLatestSemVerShouldConstruct.class) 
        return allTests
    } }

TestRunner.run(AllTests.suite())
```

The problem is that I need to use `SemVer.groovy` in my jenkins scripts that live in `vars/`. To do that I assume I need to remove the line `package vars`.

When I do that I get:

```
Compilation incomplete: expected to find the class vars.SemVer in file:/home/groovy/scripts/vars/SemVer.groovy, but the file contains the classes: SemVer
```

How can I import the class to `tests/SemVerTests.groovy` without defining the package in SemVer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `vars` to the classpath (see below), remove the `package` from `SemVers` and just `import SemVers` in your test.

```sh
$ find .
.
./tests
./tests/SemVerTests.groovy
./vars
./vars/SemVer.groovy
$ head -n 4 vars/SemVer.groovy 
class SemVer {
    private String _original
    SemVer(String original) { this._original = original }
    String toString() { return "${this._original}" }
$ head -n 8 tests/SemVerTests.groovy 
import groovy.util.GroovyTestSuite 
import junit.framework.Test 
import junit.textui.TestRunner 
import SemVer

class GetLatestSemVerShouldConstruct extends GroovyTestCase {
    void testDisplay() {
        def actual = new SemVer("Hello World!").toString()
$ groovy -cp vars  tests/SemVerTests.groovy      
.
Time: 0.035

OK (1 test)
```